# Workflow emails don't send

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a very basic workflow that I added to a list.  Basically, I just want to send an email to myself.  I created the workflow to send an email and then end the workflow.  When I add an item to the list, I can check the workflow and see that it is running.  Eventually, it moves itself to the completed stage.  I see the workflow services are running appropriately on the workflow server, but no email ever comes.  Sharepoint can send emails, so I'm a bit perplexed as to why I'm not getting emails from the workflow.  I don't have any error messages in the event viewer.  How else can I debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found a Claims Authentication error on the web front end server that detailed Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion .  I reset the IIS on the web front end and it appeared to kick everything through.